# Parse certain string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:
    var string = "something/123/bah/234/id/835/param/2343";

I want to just target the "835" that I need from "id".  Any quick ways to strip that out?

Answer (score 0):

Split it; take the sixth object:

```
var string = "something/123/bah/234/id/835/param/2343"
var id = string.split("/")[5]; // "id" is 835 now
```

Or, if you want to get your id if it is located right after `id/` and the location of `id/` can change:

```
var string = "something/123/bah/234/id/835/param/2343".split("/");
var id = string[string.indexOf("id")+1]; // "id" is 835 now
if(id==string[0]){id="No ID found"} // ...that's just if id happens not to be in your string
```

Comment: Or loop through the split looking for the array id of `id` then add one for the value (if the url is likely to change)

Comment: Thanks, but I might not know that it's in the 5th spot every time.

Comment: You should store splitted text in variable instead of calling split 3 times.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer and? Please explain your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If the number you want to extract is not necessarily the sixth part but you know that it's after the string `id` and consists of numbers you can use a regex

```
var id_part = string.match(/id\/(\d+)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the url will change and only id remain but in different place, then you can use regex:

```
var id = string.match(/id\/([^\/]+)/i)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex, and pull out the id from a capture group. This would grab the id no matter what the position.

```
var string = "something/123/bah/234/id/835/param/2343";
var regex = /\/id\/(\d+)\//g
var match = regex.exec(string)
alert(match[1]); // 835
```